# MongoDB fetching result inside the Object

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to query the data inside object in mongoDb. For example my document is

```
{
  _id: Object('XXXX')
  sensor_id: 3
  _values: Object
  received_at: 2021-12-12
}
```

and inside object I have values which is dynamic. For sensor_id 3 type I have humidity, temperature, etc. So I am looking to fetch the feeds whose humidity is greater than 97. When I am running like this `db.collection.find({ _values.humidity: { $gte : 97} })` It's working as it should be.

My question is how can I get the values from REST API because when I am using query like `_values.humidity[gt]=97`. I am not getting this request inside req.query.

So my api become like this
`172.61.25.49:3000/api/v1/feeds/?feed_values.humidity[gte]=97`

How can I get the this in my code from GET request ?

Comment: are you trying to make a server? If so, can share your server code?

Comment: yes its an express nodejs api. I have updated the my api as well

Comment: What does the code that you're using to get the query string look like?